# OSX shell command for screenshot of the active window, or xwininfo equivalent

Tags: macos, shell, window, screenshot

I am looking for an OSX shell command equivalent of Linux's `scrot -u`, which takes a screenshot of the active window (please note that this is for an automated script that shouldn't prompt the user to click on the desired window at every screenshot).

A possible alternative is an OSX equivalent of `xwininfo`, which gives coordinates and dimensions of the desired window, that I could use for an automated crop on a full screenshot.

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I hope you will get the right answer.

Comment: Ahh the option you want isn't documented on the man page. It's -l<windowid>. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/how-do-i-find-the-windowid-to-pass-to-screencapture-l

Answer (score 0):

[QuickGrab](https://github.com/vorgos/QuickGrab) makes this easy as it captures the current active window for you without worrying about window id.

You use it like this:

```
$ sleep 2 ; ./quickgrab -file ~/Desktop/Screenshot-`date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'`.png
```

If you use the binary from [this PR](https://github.com/vorgos/QuickGrab/pull/1), then it will also capture the active Chrome window.